# Installing Software not in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: installation, software-center, lazarus

I find installing software from the software center straightforward and easy.  However, I find it very confusing (actually impossible to install other software).  Could you generate (for absolute novices) a narrated Youtube video demonstrating how to do this?

Specifically, the Lazarus / Pascal programming IDE in the software center is not the most current one and has a lot of bugs.  In Windows I loaded the current version and it works beautifully.  Also, could you add Lazarus ver. 1.0.8 with FPC 2.6.2 to the software center while I am getting up to speed installing software without the Ubuntu center.

Comment: What is the main question? Install software without the use of USC? or install the latest version of Lazarus/Pascal? Or how/when we will add Lazarus 1.0.8 with FPC 2.6.2 to the repositories?

Answer (score 1):

This way work if you have problems to launch normally Software Center

$ sudo software-center

If doesn't work then install Gdebi

$ sudo apt-get install gdebi

Then you can download .deb packages and install with it

Also you can try with Synaptic, a old-fashion but it works :D

$ sudo apt-get install synaptic

You can search repositories there.

These are the easy ways to install packages, Another is Downloading .tar.bz2 (code) and compiling.

First you need uncompress then put in the folder at terminal.

$ cd /home/user/folder/of/your/program

Tree easy steps

$ ./configure

$ make

$ sudo make install

If you have any trouble doing this you can copy paste, then share with us the problem

Answer (score 0):

Its also easy to install without software center.

To install, just download the file of choice, the [32bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20i386%20DEB/) or the [64bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/) depending on your Ubuntu installation.  Once the download is done, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded ( Probably the Downloads folder), and run the command(s) below:

```
Sudo dpkg <file_name.deb>
```

You'll have to do that for both Lazarus, and FPC